# Ordinary differential equation system with maximum value of x+y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've got the following simple system of ODEs:
x': x*(1-x-y)
y': y*(1-a* y-b* x).

Plotting the system in a x' y' plot is not fully satisfying to me as what I want to achieve is that the sum of x and y, has a constant value, as I am simulating a space which is fully occupied by the species x and y, e.g. with no empty space in between. Thus, if my total space has a value of 10, and y gets a value of 8, x must automatically get a value of 2.

So, for example I could substitute x for 10-y and get:
y': y*(1-a*y - b *(10-y)).

And then I could look at the y versus t plot and by that I could also derive the x-value as x = 10 - y.

As I am quite new to ODEs, my one and only question actually is, is this a correct way of doing or is there another way? To me it sounds logical on the one hand, but on the other hand, I will obviously lose the ODE for x', as this ODE will now simply become a 'filler-up'  to get to the maximum value. Or maybe there is also a way to look at the maximum value by conserving the system? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, I have already performed the full analysis of the system, found the equilibrium points, the eigenvalues, the null-clines, trace and determinant etc, but the problem is that I want to change this system such, that x+y is always a constant value. This will obviously change the system and everything I have obtained so far. For example, if a point at (8, 2) would eventually go to (1,0), this would violate my rule that x + y = 10.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The y' equation is set with respect to the x' equation, so the x' equation is 'freezed' and not changed. 
The y'-equation can be varied, as we have a and b which are variable parameters and also k in k*y (in this case k was 1). K needs to be positive though as it is a growth rate (with respect to x), and so need a and b. Hope that explains a little bit more.

Comment: If $x'$ is fixed and you want to conserve $x+y$ then $y' = -x' = -x(1-x-y)$.

Comment: Sounds reasonable indeed, but then I'll lose my a and b parameters right? I'd want to keep them, and I don't necessarily want to constrain myself to stay in the system, cause obviously that's an hard task. But then I'd have this y' t equation with "x'" only as filler-up to get to 10 and that might not be accurate for all cases.

Comment: A particle physicist would now look for hidden extra dimensions. :-)